# filtering CSV in Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I am currently compiling a list of software installed on computers. My end goal is to filter out all baseline software so I can get an accurate report of installs. I am forced to search an area of the registry that captures a lot of extra fluff that gets entered during the install. Originally I created a "baseline.csv" to scrub the capture with, but this file is getting to large and unmanageable due to constant updates. So I figured it would be easier and quicker to create an "abovebaseline.csv" file to scrub out the baseline and keep items that match the software listed in abovebasline.

After capturing the list of software I currently run this to scrub out the baseline.

```
$BaselineSoftware = Import-Csv $PSScriptRoot\baseline.csv

$InstalledSoftware = Import-Csv $PSScriptRoot\ALLsoftware.csv


Foreach($software in $BaselineSoftware)

   {

   $InstalledSoftware = $InstalledSoftware | where {$($_.ProductName) -ne $($software.ProductName) }

   }

$InstalledSoftware | Export-Csv -Path $PSScriptRoot\software.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I figured it would be easy and just change the -ne to -eq and the contents of the baseline file and name to abovebaseline. However when I run it the software.csv file is empty.

```
$AboveBaselineSoftware = Import-Csv $PSScriptRoot\AboveBaselineSoftware.csv

$InstalledSoftware = Import-Csv $PSScriptRoot\ALLsoftware.csv


Foreach($software in $AboveBaselineSoftware)

   {

   $InstalledSoftware = $InstalledSoftware | where {$($_.ProductName) -eq $($software.ProductName) }

   }

$InstalledSoftware | Export-Csv -Path $PSScriptRoot\software.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

I also have messed around with Compare-Object cmdlet but I've had no luck. It seems there are multiple ways to removed duplicates, but not keep like items. Anyone able to help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what's in each csv or at least the baseline? Just a small subset of what's actually in those?

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the `$InstalledSoftware` collection repeatedly in the `foreach` loop. Try

```
$AboveBaselineSoftware = Import-Csv $PSScriptRoot\AboveBaselineSoftware.csv
$InstalledSoftware     = Import-Csv $PSScriptRoot\ALLsoftware.csv

$ChosenSoftware = foreach ($software in $AboveBaselineSoftware)
   {
       $InstalledSoftware | where { $($_.ProductName) -eq $($software.ProductName) }
   }

$ChosenSoftware | Export-Csv -Path $PSScriptRoot\software.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

or even

```
$AboveBaselineSoftware = Import-Csv $PSScriptRoot\AboveBaselineSoftware.csv
$InstalledSoftware     = Import-Csv $PSScriptRoot\ALLsoftware.csv

$ChosenSoftware = $InstalledSoftware | 
    Where-Object { $_.ProductName -in $AboveBaselineSoftware.ProductName }

$ChosenSoftware | Export-Csv -Path $PSScriptRoot\software.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1):

Short version of JosefZ ;)

```
$AboveBaselineSoftware = Import-Csv $PSScriptRoot\AboveBaselineSoftware.csv

Import-Csv $PSScriptRoot\ALLsoftware.csv | Where ProductName -in $AboveBaselineSoftware.ProductName | Export-Csv $PSScriptRoot\software.csv -NoType
```